# Connecting Front End with Back End Mongodb (MERN)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I am trying to connect front end sign in page to backend mongodb. I am getting error as mention below.
This code gets data from the front end and sends the register tag of the back end.

```
    name: "",
    email: "",
  });

  let name, value;
  const handleInputs = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    name = e.target.name;
    value = e.target.value;

    setuser({ ...user, [name]: value });
  };

  const PostData = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // http://localhost:3002/register
    const [name, email] = user;
    console.log(name);
    console.log(email);
    const res = await fetch("/register", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name,
        email,
      }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(name);
    console.log(email);
    if (data.status === 422 || !data) {
      window.alert("Invalid Registeration");
    } else {
      window.alert(" Registeration Successfull");
    }
  };
```

Error messages:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: user is not iterable at PostData (App.js:30:1) at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1) at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1) at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1) at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1) at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1) at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)

at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1) at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1) at react-dom.development.js:9288:1
```

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: user is not iterable
    at PostData (App.js:30:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)

Comment: at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:1

Comment: The error seems to suggest that `user` is not something that you can spread or loop through (the `not iterable` part). Looking at this part: `setuser({ ...user, [name]: value });`, I'm guessing that's where the error is. **EDIT** You can wrap that part in a `try / catch` block, and see if the catch will trigger, just to be sure that this is what's causing an unhandled / uncaught exception.

Answer (score 0):

looks like something is wrong with the user object ,you can try to log it see what it's giving at every step, try JSON.parse(), Also I can see you are passing name, email to JSON.strigfy() instead of that try another way and destructure in this way const { name, email } = user not  const [name, email ] = user ;